# Как сформировать запрос методом execute в VK api?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, vkscript

Прошу пояснить, никак не могу понять!

Пробую себя в [VK api](https://vk.com/dev/manuals), знания php поверхностные...

Загружаю информацию с помощью curl:

```
    function GetVK($url, $params) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Формирую запрос:

```
$code .= 'var out = API.users.get({...});'; 
$code .= 'var out = out + API.groups.getById({...});'; 
$code .= 'var out = out + API.stats.get({...});'; 
$code .= 'return out;';
```

Отправляю запрос

```
$execute = json_decode(GetVK('https://api.vk.com/method/execute', array(
    'code' => $code,
    'access_token' => mc_decrypt($_SESSION['UserInfo']['access_token'], ENCRYPTION_KEY),
    'v' => $System['api']['version']
)), true);
```

---

На выходе получил массив `$execute['response']`, получается на следующем уровне у меня 3 массива, которые соответствуют 3 моим запросам в порядке очереди!?

Правильно?

Просто меня терзают сомнения, что я не правильно делаю запрос и считываю данные...

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может не совсем уловил суть вопроса, правильнее бы разделить массивы:

```
$code .= 'var users = API.users.get({...});'; 
$code .= 'var groups = out + API.groups.getById({...});'; 
$code .= 'var stats = out + API.stats.get({...});'; 
$code .= 'return {"users": users, "groups": groups, "stats": stats};';
```

Comment: видимо мы не поняли друг друга...
выше вы цитировали мой запрос, в нем я обращаюсь к 3 разным методам, а на выходе получаю один большой общий массив... Вопрос - может я не правильно делаю запрос и можно получить ответ разбитый на запросы?

Comment: @Dimastik86, а что такое "ответ разбитый на запросы"? Результат хоть как придет один массив, но чтобы не было путаницы в моем коде будет разбит на именованные подмассивы

Comment: похоже это то что мне нужно, спасибо! попробую, отпишусь! )